# Is it possible for pagination to make calls to the RESTFul layer and query only the information it displays?

Tags: angularjs, rest, pagination

Right now I have a pagination table that was built in AngularJS that queries all the records at once and displays 10/20/50/100 entries per page depending on which option is selected. However, I was wondering if there was a known way to make it so that the pagination makes the rest layer only query how many entries are displayed.

For example, if I have 150 total records in the database and I only want to display 50 records per page by pagination, then I only query record 1-50 records through the rest layer. Then when I go to the next page the rest layer queries the next 50 records (51=100). And for page three, the rest layer queries records 101-150, so it only queries the records I try to display at any one time, If I go back to page 1, then it queries records 1-50 again.

Is there a way to do this that isn't overtly complicated? I'm just curious

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example if you use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

On screen load, retrieve only first 50 elements. For further navigation you have access to `ng-change` event which can do the post request to retrive data based on limited number of elements on the new page requested.